# Is there a way to play BS Zelda: Inishie no Sekiban?

Tags: emulation, snes

I've been wanting to play Inishie no Sekiban, a Zelda game which is difficult to find because it was broadcasted to the Super Nintendo a few times in the 1990s.

So far I haven't been unable to locate a translation of the game or any ROMs.

**Are there playable copies of BS Zelda Inishie no Sekiban?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"BS Zelda Inishie no Sekiban", translated to English is "BS The Legend of Zelda: The Ancient Stone Tablets".

Doing a quick google search for the English title has provided a few links* for downloads of the rom.

<sup>*Pun somewhat intended.</sup>

Comment: Thank you! I didn't think of looking for a translation...

Comment: Not only have they fully translated the game and made it playable, but they've also created ways to integrate translated versions of the original voice acting, and orchestrated music.